# Rails, SQL: IN AND NOT IN (subselect)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to sql statements in rails and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way of calling the following:

```
following = "SELECT following_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
Activity.includes(:user, :target).where("user_id IN (#{following}) AND
                targeted_user_id NOT IN (#{following})", user_id: user.id)
```

Without knowing much about SQL, the way the above statement calls the subselect twice doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to do this, maybe calling the subselect once only?

#### EDIT

The above works as intended, it creates:

```
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = 1) AND targeted_user_id NOT IN (SELECT following_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = 1))
```

The only thing I'm unsure about is that the query uses the subselect twice, therefore should the value of the subselect be cached and then used, or can the code statement be written in a way that the subselect is only run once, something like:

```
.where("user_id IN AND targeted_user_id NOT IN (#{following})", user_id: user.id)
```

TBH I'm not even sure if there is a problem with the code in the first place, like I said, it just doesn't feel write using the subselect twice in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `following` variable will only contain the set where `following_id = :user_id`.

Thereby the `user_id` is always in `following`, and `targeted_user_id` is never in it. 
Unless `targeted_user_id` is the same as `user_id`.

Maybe an SQL query like:

```
following = "SELECT following_id FROM relationships"
Activity.includes(:user, :target)
        .where("user_id IN (#{following}) 
                AND targeted_user_id NOT IN (#{following})"
               ,user_id: user.id, targeted_user_id: target.id)
```

As I don't quite know what your code is supposed to do, it may not be exactly what you need. Could be that a better solution, if you have the `user_id` and `targeted_user_id` before making the initial SQL statement, you would want something like:

```
following = "SELECT following_id FROM relationships
             WHERE following_id = :user_id
             AND following_id != :target_user_id"
```

That could perhaps return the set you needed.